# no IP address for certain MAC

Tags: wireless, dhcp, ip-address, dhclient

Please assist-

I have a wifi radio that will not obtain an IP via DHCP. Basically, a DISCOVER packet is sent to the DHCP server, the DHCP server receives the packet, then responds with an OFFER but the wifi radio never shows it being received per the device logs and then timesout at 120 sec, then restarts DORA all over- just a continuous circle! I am happy to provide logs or any output requested to help resolve this issue.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

**UPDATED 08/29/18**

So I have determined that the issue of no ip address assignment via DHCP has something to do with my MAC address. I am hopeful for responses as to what this means. I can assume this because I changed the MAC address and watched the logs correctly report the DHCP (DORA) process in full action, then I was assigned an IP. After this result, I then reverted the MAC to the original address and WHAM! no ip address, and the logs show the same as previously reported, DISCOVERY (5x) then max timeout... DISCOVERY, timeout. And from the DHCP server, a DISCOVER packet is sent to the DHCP server, the DHCP server receives the packet, then responds with an OFFER but the wifi radio never shows it being received per the device logs and then timesout at 120 sec, then restarts DORA all over- just a continuous circle!

I am so confused, please assist.

Comment: Is Network Manager running here? From the terminal: `ps aux | grep -i network` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: here is the output: st        4162  0.0  0.0   8880   776 pts/5    R+   14:43   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network

Comment: Use `wireshark` to watch the packets. DHCP can be picky.

Comment: yes, of course! So I did a capture off the wireless interface and inspected the packets. All DHCP packets mirrored the DHCP tail log:  sent DISCOVERYx5, then max timeout, sent DISCOVERYx5, max timeout etc.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you simply trying to connect? Wired ethernet or wireless? Please tell us the exact command you are using.

Comment: The issue is no IP address assignment via the DHCP server. So I cannot connect on the network. Must be assigned via DHCP, not allowed to set static address. The real question is why and where is the breakdown when my adaptor shows DISCOVERY sent then timeout from not seeing any OFFER reply from the DHCP, and the DHCP logs show DISCOVERY received and OFFER sent to wireless interface.

Comment: BTW, I have two wireless cards in my device, the exact same make/model, no issues on that one. Verified that drivers are up to date. I need them both to work to provide seamless hand-off to other APs as I roam around the office.